# Sorting problems in tableView with Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview

Thank you for your future help! That's my struct array:

```
var malls: [Mall] = [ 
    mall(name:"yagey", distance:""), 
    mall[name:"tigey", distance:"") 
]
```

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

```
    var mall = malls[index]

    let mallLocate = CLLocation(latitude: mall.latitude, longitude: mall.longitude)

    let distanceInMeters = mallLocate.distance(from: coords) / 1000

    let distanceInMetersString = String(format: "%.1f", distanceInMeters)


    for index in 0..<malls.count {
        var mall = malls[index] // copy a mall value
        mall.distance = distanceInMetersString // change the copy of mall
        malls[index] = mall // put the updated mall back into the array
    }

    malls.sort() { $0.distance < $1.distance }
```

How can I sort malls by mall.distance?
Please, help me, I can't understand what is wrong :(

That's my tableView

tableView

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! EateriesTableViewCell
    let mall = mallToDisplayAt(indexPath: indexPath)
    let mallLocate = CLLocation(latitude: mall.latitude, longitude: mall.longitude)
    print (mallLocate)
    cell.distanceLabel.text = distanceInMetersString + "км"
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you will have to sort your array of malls first in the viewdidload for example then after the sorting reload your tableviews data

```
 self.tableView.reloadData()
```

and in your cell for row will be like this :

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! EateriesTableViewCell
let mall = mallToDisplayAt(indexPath: indexPath.row)
let mallLocate = CLLocation(latitude: mall.latitude, longitude: mall.longitude)
print (mallLocate)

let distanceInMeters = mallLocate.distance(from: coords) / 1000

let distanceInMetersString = String(format: "%.1f", distanceInMeters)

cell.distanceLabel.text = distanceInMetersString + "км"
print (mall.distance)


return cell
```

}

Comment: please, watch the code I post again,, it doesn't work too

Comment: you are setting the value of the mall distance in all the object with the same value 

        mall.distance = distanceInMetersString // change the copy of mall

you should re calculate the mall distance for each object 

       var mall = malls[index] // copy a mall value
    let mallLocate = CLLocation(latitude: mall.latitude, longitude: mall.longitude)

    let distanceInMeters = mallLocate.distance(from: coords) / 1000
    let distanceInMetersString = String(format: "%.1f", distanceInMeters)
    mall.distance = distanceInMetersString + "км"
         malls[index] = mall

Comment: I really appreciate your help, thank you, but I can't understand what I'm doing wrong here, I have problems with adressing to mall struct, I think.. Can you watch the code again? Thank you, really
    Cannot subscript a value of type '[Mall]' with an index of type '(Any) -> Int' 
when var mall = malls[index] in viewDidLoad

Answer (score 0):

Your sort code is just fine. Put it outside of delegate method.

What is the point of having this for loop inside delegate method

```
for index in 0..<malls.count {
        var mall = malls[index] // copy a mall value
        mall.distance = distanceInMetersString // change the copy of mall
        malls[index] = mall // put the updated mall back into the array
    }
```

Here you are setting distance property of all the objects in array distanceInMetersString.

If you want sorting please do the sort coding  **outside tableView delegate methods**. And **remove the for loop** mentioned above. And after sorting just reload the tableview :)

Comment: thank you for your help, really, is it what you mean? (please see the post) but it's
     `Cannot subscript a value of type '[Mall]' with an index of type '(Any) -> Int' when var mall = malls[index]` in viewDidLoad

Comment: @DimitriyChigarikhin : In your viewDidLoad method, the first line is var mall = malls[index].   where are you declaring index. I could not see any variable index other than the for loop controll index.